# Buoyant Air Kinetic Energy in a Lagrangian Approach to Derive Airship Equation of Motion

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism, aircraft

I am currently working on deriving airship equations of motion, in a fluid in motion (unsteady and non-uniform wind). The article cited in most sources is *[Equations of Motion of a Vehicle in a Moving Fluid](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245429568_Equations_of_Motion_of_a_Vehicle_in_a_Moving_Fluid)* (Peter G. Thomasson, Journal of Aircraft, DOI: 10.2514/2.2645).

The derivation of the equation of motion is done using a Lagrangian approach, on the system shown in the figure below. I am struggling on the definition of the kinetic energy (more precisely on the kinetic energy of the fluid displaced by the vehicle)

|  |
| --- |
| [image] |

Consider a rigid vehicle moving in a perfect fluid that is circulating in a multiply connected vessel, with the vessel itself accelerating. Consider also a set of axes fixed in the vehicle’s body, and a non-accelerating set of Earth axes. The approximation used is that if the vehicle’s velocity is made equal to the velocity of the fluid, and its mass is made equal to that of the displaced fluid, then the energy is the same as it would be, if the vehicle were absent and the space occupied by the fluid.

All the following quantities are evaluated in vehicle body axes:

$$x = (u, v, w, p, q, r)^T$$ which represents the vehicle’s velocity relative to the Earth axes,

$$ x_f = (u_f , v_f , w_f , 0, 0, 0)^T$$ the vessel’s velocity relative to the Earth axes, and
$$x_c = (u_c, v_c, w_c, 0, 0, 0)$$ the steady circulating velocity relative to the vessel that would exist if the vehicle were absent.
we define the relative velocity as $x_r = x - x_f - x_c $.

We can then write the Lagrangian of the system, including the bulk translation of the multiply connected fluid, by building up a description of the total kinetic energy via the following steps:

1. Following Lamb, we consider the case where the fluid has cyclic irrotational motion through channels in the enclosing vessel and assume that it is independent of the motion of the vehicle itself. As shown by Lamb, such cyclic irrotational motion can be impulsively generated from rest. We shall denote the associated kinetic energy by $K_0$
2. Impose an impulsive force on the vessel so as to accelerate it to $x_f$; in this case the additional kinetic energy is $$\frac{M_f x_f^T x_f}{2} \ ,$$ where $M_f$ is the mass of fluid contained in the vessel.
3. Take the fluid mass that occupies the space that will ultimately be occupied by the vehicle and accelerate it, via a set of impulsive pressures over its surface, to the same speed as the vehicle. In that case, the kinetic energy will increase on two counts, first the increase in kinetic energy of the fluid mass that will be ultimately replaced by the vehicle and second the increase in kinetic energy of the surrounding fluid due to the increased velocity. The latter, can be represented in terms of the added mass. Thus, the extra energy is $$\frac{x_r^T (M_r + M_i)x_r}{2}$$ where $M_r$ is the $6 \times 6$ added mass matrix and $M_i$ is the $6 \times 6$ displaced fluid mass matrix.
4. Finally, we remove the fluid from the space that is to be occupied by the vehicle; this reduces the kinetic energy by $$\frac{x^T M_i x}{2}$$ and replaces it with the actual vehicle, thereby increasing the energy by $$\frac{x^T M_v x}{2}$$ where $M_v$ is the $6 \times 6$ vehicle mass matrix.

I struggle on the step number 3. To me, the kinetic energy necessary to accelerate the fluid from $x_f+x_c$ up to $x$ should lead to an extra energy of: $$\frac{1}{2}x^T (M_r + M_i)x - \frac{1}{2} (x_f+x_c)^T (M_r + M_i)(x_f+x_c) = \frac{1}{2} (x+x_f+x_c)^T (M_r + M_i)(x-x_f-x_c) = \frac{1}{2} (x+x_f+x_c)^T (M_r + M_i)x_r \ . $$

Do I miss something here?